# How do I edit text files in filezilla?

Tags: 16.04, filezilla

I clicked on View/Edit but the file does not open. I added "/usr/bin/gedit" to the custom editor but it does nothing.

Comment: I even tried txt "/usr/bin/gedit" in filetype associations. but when i click on view/edit nothing appears ???

Comment: What kind of file is it (text file or maybe a binary file)? Are you trying to edit a local file or a remote file? What happens if you try a text mode editor, for example `nano`?

Comment: @sudodus it is a text file that I uploaded to the server. I can open it via command line but not through the filezilla gui

Comment: What do you mean by command line? Via `ssh`? In that case, have you tried `gedit` that way via `ssh -X`? It may work better with another GUI editor, for example `leafpad` or `geany`.

Comment: I tested in Lubuntu 19.04 with Filezilla  3.39.0 and gedit - Version 3.32.0 and it works for me to edit remote files, even when gedit is not installed in the [Lubuntu 18.04.1 based] server. Maybe there is a bug in Filezilla of 16.04?